# Issue with php/mysql inserting entry with checkbox checked into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Below is the code from catalog page with the data which has to be inserted to the database. It has some problem and i cant insert that data to the database table, and i think i have not ported variables correctly.

My catalogue page has this code (it is for purchasing photographs):

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
echo "<tr><td width=100><img src=".$row['FilePath']." /></td>";
    echo "<td width=100 padding=25>".$row['Title']."</td>"; $hour = time() + 3600; setcookie('titlecookie', $row['Title'], $hour); 
    echo "<td width=100 padding=25>".$row['Cost']."</td>";
echo "<td width=100>".$row['FileSize']."</td>";
echo "<td width=100>".$row['CaptureDate']."</td>";
echo "<td width=100>".$row['Resolution']."</td>";
echo "<td width=100><input type=checkbox name=checked[] value=select />Purchase</td></tr>";
 }
 echo "</table><input type=submit name=submit value=Purchase></form></center>";
}
else
{
  echo "Query not successful";
}
```

The code for my purchase page appears as follows:

```
$username = "COOKIE['ID_my_site']";

$title = "COOKIE['titlecookie']";

$Custid = mysql_query("SELECT Custid from Customer Where Username=$username");

$Money = $_POST['Cost'];

$Photoid = mysql_query("SELECT Photoid from Photograph Where Title = $row[Title]");

foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $select) {

if(mysql_query('INSERT INTO Transaction (Money, Custid)
      VALUES ($Money, $Custid)'))
{
  echo "successfully added to Transaction";
}
    else
    {
        echo "Problems adding data to Transaction";
    } 



if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO TransPhoto (Photoid, Transid)
      VALUES ('$Photoid', '$Transid')"))
{
  echo "successfully added to Transphoto";
}
    else
    {
        echo "Problems adding data to Transphoto";
    }

}
```

Could you possible assist me with fixing this code? I am relatively new to this but have searched and could not find an effective solution. Thanks

Comment: `$username = "COOKIE['ID_my_site']";` da hell is this? You mean $_COOKIE[...] ? Most of your queries won't work, since passing a string to mysql should be surrounded by quotes i.e. `WHERE username = '$username'`

Comment: Whenever I had them I was getting errors of unexpected " and so on. I removed them and didn't get these errors.

Comment: Read about escaping, interpolating, etc? You can pass single variable with quotes to a double quoted string, but you need to escape quotes if it's array, which also contains single quotes, or use curly braces -> `'{$row['username']}'`

Comment: Aside from these syntax issues, can you identify any glaringly obvious problems? Like with major syntax/method?

Comment: It looks compilingly OK (and in the same time designed awful, but I guess, so far so good). Change your cookie values aswell. $username is now string "`COOKIE['ID_my_site']`", but not a real cookie. P.S.: All of your checkboxes has the same value

Comment: I keep getting Undefined index: ID_my_site, Undefined index: Cost, Undefined variable: row, Undefined index: checked, and also Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: do you have setcookie() somewhere? How do you get cookies, we haven't seend this. Your queries are called $photoid, $custid, none of them is $result, but you are assinign fetch_assoc to the $result variable. Where did it come from?

Comment: The cookie for the user is when they log in. . .this part of my website works. The result part is above what I posted: $getdataqry = "SELECT * from Photograph ORDER BY Title ASC";
  
   // Execute the query
   
   $result = mysql_query($getdataqry);
   
   if($result)
   {
   
   // Show the output in a table
  
     echo "<center><form action=Purchase.php><table border=1 width=75%>";
   
     while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
 echo "<tr><td width=100><img src=".$row['FilePath']." /></td>";
        echo "<td wid. . .and son on as per above

Comment: The part is incomplete. So `ID_my_site` is a cookie name, set by setcookie(), right? So far so good. Rendering the table with the submit button also works ok, right? You need to have <form> tag with action and method="POST", since you trying to grab by $_POST[]

Comment: Yes ID_my_site is the username. This is et when they log in. The table for selecting the image to purchase renders perfectly. I'm just trying to get the variables for customer id and photoid, and enter these into a table called Transaction

Comment: add method="POST" to your form tag.

Comment: Yes have done. Still get undefined index errors

Comment: OK, int your HTML I don't see any name="cost", but you are trying to access $_POST['cost'], also $CustId is not actual value, it's just a query, you need to fetch it. If it's one row, one field, you can with mysql_result(). Otherwise, you need fetch_assoc/array. You have forreached the checkbox to $select, but never used it. What's the point?

Comment: Same applies for $Photoid as $Custid, they both need to be fetched

Comment: Regarding the Cost part - in the HTML, where it says $row['Cost'] - that is what I want to be adding for cost. I just used POST[Cost] because I thought that would bring it across. How can I bring that value across? I have changed the MySQL_result part now. s it right to just have $Custid = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT Custid from Customer Where Username='$username'")); ?

Comment: Yes, it's ok this way for $Custid, do the same for $Photoid. <td> values are not passed, You need to have input. For example: `echo "<input type=hidden name=cost value=$row[cost] />"`, now you will have input field with name cost, which will be posted. $Transid also comes from nowhere.

Comment: OK I have added the hidden input. The transid is supposed to be the auto-incremented id that comes from having a transaction. I'm not sure how to set up this one either. I assume it would involve fetching it AFTER having inserted the original data into the transaction table, no?

Comment: If your column is autroincrement index in MySQL, just insert NULL value i.e. `INSERT INTO table (id, name) VALUES ('', 'name1');`

Comment: OK I fixed the undefined index with the cookie for the username. I still get it for the row and for transid. If I can get the row part working then the other should follow afterwards.

Comment: The row part also needs to be posted, in order to be transfered to the other page. Put it into hidden field again, and access it via $_POST[]

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit stuck on it all at the moment, and I've got to go. If you get a chance, could you perhaps write out what you think would work? Thanks for your help, but I seem to be on a roundabout at the moment with it

Comment: `echo "<input type=hidden name=title value=$row[title] />` and on the next page `"SELECT Photoid from Photograph Where Title = $_POST[title]"`

Comment: OK, so at the moment my code on the Purchase page is as follows:$username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'];

$Custid = mysql_query("SELECT Custid from Customer Where Username='$username'");

$Money = $_POST['Cost'];
  
foreach ($_POST['checked'] as $select) {
 
   if(mysql_query('INSERT INTO Transaction (Money, Custid)
          VALUES ($Money, $Custid)'))
  {
      echo "successfully added to Transaction";
  }
        else
        {
            echo "Problems adding data to Transaction";
        } 

 } I now get no php error, but I get Problems adding data to transaction. What could be the problem/s?

Comment: $custid is still not a mysql_result

Comment: I got it working! It adds to transaction. Yay! Thanks for your help. I have a couple of things to ask though: It inputs money to the table as 0.00, when the actual value for the money is 0.99. Secondly, if the user has selected multiple images, it adds each image as it's own transaction, when I would like them to be added all as one transaction. Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe the problem may lie in this line: <input type=hidden name=Cost value="$row['Cost']" />".$row['Cost']."       Is the value not being picked up? It displays 0.99 in the list, but is not adding it as 0.99

Comment: no, the problem is that $custid is just mysql resource, but not a result, as we discussed yesterday, you need to fetch its value

Comment: The custid part works. . .I've echoed it and it gave me the logged in username

Comment: So it's a string. Quote the variables in your query.

Comment: INSERT INTO Transaction (Money, Custid)
          VALUES ("$Money", "$Custid")') or die(mysql_error())) Do you mean like this? Because it still isn't inserting the decimal value properly

Comment: Yes, how does it insert it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. . .but I seriously think this part: <input type=hidden name=Cost value="$row['Cost']" />".$row['Cost']." is not actually storing the 0.99 as the value. . .when I echo it I get 0.00

Comment: if you have echo "... before <input type... you have to escape the quotes, because you will end up with twice double quoted string, which will break the syntax. You surely need to learn some basics around quoting, strings, integers, POSTing, querying, then try all of it at once.

Comment: OK I've escaped the quotes: <input type=hidden name=Cost value=".$row['Cost']." />".$row['Cost']."</td>     but it still isn't adding 0.99, it adds 0.00

Comment: Ok I see what you mean with not fetching the result of the Custid part. When I have this code:        $Custid = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT Custid from Customer Where Username='$username'"));     I get this error:     Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: Did you read what mysql_fetch_object does? $custId would become object, which property `Custid`, constains your desired info. You need to call property `Custid` via object `$CustId`

Comment: Sorry to be a bother, you don't know what this helps means for me. . . but could you type out the code for what you just said? I don't really understand what you are saying

Comment: I mean you might need to use later in your query `'{$Custid->Custid}'` instead of only '$Custid'

Comment: OMG IT WORKS!! Thank you so much! Do you have an idea as to how I could have one transaction with more than just one photograph per transaction? And it would add the Costs? At the moment, for instance if I have two images selected, it creates two transactions, each with cost = 0.99

Comment: The foreach should do this, but set the value of each checkbox with the name of the image or something unique